# JOIN in MYSQL with Count or Sum

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I am trying to execute a query with a join.  If I use 'nil' as `numcomments`, I get all the stories, but if I try to count them with `COUNT` anything, it limits the stories to just the stories with comments.  What I want is to get back all the stories but give a zero if the count is zero

Here is the schema

```
//stories
id|story
1|Microsoft Announces Earnings
2|Apple Inks Content Deal
3|Google In Talks With Nissan
4|Netflix Greenlights Series

//comments
id|storyid|comment
1|1|Not what I would have expected
2|1|Look at numbers for Azure
3|1|I called this
4|3|Who cares

Here is the query:
This only returns the stories with commments ie stories 1 and 3

$sql = "
SELECT COUNT(c.comment) numcomments
     , s.story event
     , s.id
     , c.storyid   
  FROM stories s
  LEFT 
  JOIN comments c
    ON c.storyid = s.id 
";

//this returns all the stories but does not give me a count of comments for obvious reasons

$sql = "
SELECT 'nil' numcomments
     , s.story event
     , s.id
     , c.storyid   
  FROM stories s
  LEFT 
  JOIN comments c
    ON c.storyid = s.id 
";
```

How can I get all the stories but if there are no comments just get a zero in the count or `numcomments` field

Comment: Why do you include c.storyid in the SELECT?

Comment: @strawberry, I include it because my understanding is used in the join statement it must be selected.  Is that correct?  Also on the groupby do you know the requirement for which fields to include?  Do you neeed all of them that are grouped or just one ie s.id

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to include in a GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns from the SELECT. However, if, for instance s.id is a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't  need to include s.name in the GROUP BY, because s.name is 'functionally dependant' upon s.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.story, count(c.id) as NumOfComments 
FROM stories s LEFT JOIN comments ON  s.id=c.storyid 
GROUP BY s.id, s.story
```

Comment: This worked.  Just to be clear, however, what is the rule for which fields you need to include in the group by statement.  Is it every one in the select statement that is unique to the item you want to group by or the fields that are used in the Join statements or just one of the fields such as s.id--that seems to work for me as well?

Comment: Usually the columns included in GROUP BY match those that are selected with out applying any aggregate functions on top of them. In this example s.id, s.story

Answer (score 1):

aggregate function needs `group by` which is missed in your 1st query

```
SELECT COUNT(c.comment) as `numcomments`,s.story as event,s.id,c.storyid   
FROM `stories` s
LEFT JOIN comments `c` ON 
c.storyid = s.id  group by s.story ,s.id,c.storyid
```

And 2nd query you doest have any aggregate `count()` function so its normal not showing count

Answer (score 1):

You always need to group by the columns which are not being aggregated.

Try this

```
$sql = "
SELECT COUNT(c.comment) numcomments
     , s.story event
     , s.id
     , c.storyid   
  FROM stories s
  LEFT 
  JOIN comments c
   ON c.storyid = s.id 
Group by 
s.story 
     , s.id
     , c.storyid
";
```

Comment: Not strictly true where a functional dependency occurs (as is the case above)

Comment: I had missed that this was tagged with mysql so the group by is not required for all aggregations but still needed for this, and good practice to include.